# Is OneDrive a required component in Windows 10?

Tags: onedrive, windows-10

Is OneDrive required in Windows 10? If it is, what makes it a required component?

If it isn't required, how can I disable it?

I do not use OneDrive for cloud storage; I have Dropbox for that. I'm not bothered about syncing OneNote and other Office files with the cloud either.

Comment: Right-click on the OneDrive icon and choose `Settings`.  Then click the `Unlink OneDrive` button.

Comment: @Ramhound so the only purpose of OneDrive in Windows 10 is to sync files? It doesn't sync settings or anything like that?

Comment: How is this primarily opinion based? The way I read it, it's asking if it's a technical necessity for OneDrive to be installed (will windows fail to boot without OneDrive, etc)

Answer (score 2):

One Drive is an integrated component in Windows 10 ([Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-off-or-uninstall-OneDrive-f32a17ce-3336-40fe-9c38-6efb09f944b0?fromAR=1&omkt=en-US&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)). In Windows 10 a deinstallation is not supported:

> If you don't want to use OneDrive, you can disable it, hide it on your computer, or, in some versions of Windows, uninstall it.

In Windows 10 (and 8.1) it can be either systemwide deactivated with a local group policy (requires Windows 10 Professional) or can be just hidden on a per user basis by unlinking the account, deactivating the autostart and hiding the icon in the Windows explorer. For details see the link above.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10v1709, I go into Task Manager, into the Startup list, right-click on OneDrive, and choose Disable.  This may get turned on again with future Windows Updates.

Answer (score -2):

Or you can uninstall it...

from a command prompt:
%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\OneDriveSetup.exe /uninstall